# Extend fastify logger with typesafe custom log level?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, fastify, pino

I add a custom log-level "silly".

Log with `fastify.log.silly('...')` produces a TypeScript error:

> Property 'silly' does not exist on type 'FastifyBaseLogger'.ts(2339)

How can this be type-safe extended?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fastify version >= 4.16.0, `FastifyBaseLogger` is exported as an interface instead of a type alias and you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) pattern to extend it:

```
declare module 'fastify' {
  interface FastifyBaseLogger {
    silly: FastifyLogFn;
  }
}
```

Now the complier "knows" that silly is part of the logger interface and will not produce an error when calling `fastify.log.silly('...')`